Flutter web app shows blank screen on browser
I have built a flutter app and it runs great on Anddroid. I have build the web version of this app and deployed it on a web server. When I try to run the web app I get a button that should redirect me to my app but it just opens another tab with the same button.
I have followed some of the solutions I have come across on the internet. They mostly say change the < base href = "/" > line but none of the changes work.
I don't think the script inside the index.html file is being run.
Here is my index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-database-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-functions-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-remote-config-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-performance-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- 
      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

    <style media="screen">
      body { background: #ECEFF1; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87); font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #message { background: white; max-width: 360px; margin: 100px auto 16px; padding: 32px 24px; border-radius: 3px; }
      #message h2 { color: #ffa100; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 8px; }
      #message h1 { font-size: 22px; font-weight: 300; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); margin: 0 0 16px;}
      #message p { line-height: 140%; margin: 16px 0 24px; font-size: 14px; }
      #message a { display: block; text-align: center; background: #039be5; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; color: white; padding: 16px; border-radius: 4px; }
      #message, #message a { box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24); }
      #load { color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); text-align: center; font-size: 13px; }
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        body, #message { margin-top: 0; background: white; box-shadow: none; }
        body { border-top: 16px solid #ffa100; }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="message">
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <h1>Firebase Hosting Setup Complete</h1>
      <p>You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!</p>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://deal-diligence-5de73.web.app/index.html">Open Deal Diligence</a>
    </div>
    <p id="load">Firebase SDK Loading&hellip;</p>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const loadEl = document.querySelector('#load');
        // // 
        // // The Firebase SDK is initialized and available here!
        //
        // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { });
        // firebase.database().ref('/path/to/ref').on('value', snapshot => { });
        // firebase.firestore().doc('/foo/bar').get().then(() => { });
        // firebase.functions().httpsCallable('yourFunction')().then(() => { });
        // firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(() => { });
        // firebase.storage().ref('/path/to/ref').getDownloadURL().then(() => { });
        // firebase.analytics(); // call to activate
        // firebase.analytics().logEvent('tutorial_completed');
        // firebase.performance(); // call to activate
        //
        // // 

        try {
          let app = firebase.app();
          let features = [
            'auth', 
            'database', 
            'firestore',
            'functions',
            'messaging', 
            'storage', 
            'analytics', 
            'remoteConfig',
            'performance',
          ].filter(feature => typeof app[feature] === 'function');
          loadEl.textContent = `Firebase SDK loaded with ${features.join(', ')}`;
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          loadEl.textContent = 'Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console.';
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Here is the directory structure on the web server:
public_html/index.html
Here is the main.dart file:
import 'package:deal_diligence/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:deal_diligence/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:deal_diligence/Services/firebase_api.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await FirebaseApi().initNotifications();


  runApp(const ProviderScope(
      child:
          DealDiligence())); // This allows the entire app to use River_Pod for state management
}

class DealDiligence extends StatelessWidget {
  const DealDiligence({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}

I do connect to a Firebase database if that makes a difference. I have setup a web project on the Firebase console.
Why is my initial screen blank? Is there any other code you need to see in order to help me? Please let me know.
Thank you
UPDATE:
I have a thought, since all of the Firebase SDK initialization is commented out, could this be causing the problem since I do use Firebase?

How did you deploy it? Docker? Firebase?

I simply uploaded the web build to the web server. Is that the wrong way to do it?

did you try  flutter build web --release?

I built it through Code Magic so I am not sure if it did the --release.

i am not sure about your deploy method, usually i use docker. But either way, you must build web app, and only after that you can deploy it.

I do build web app and it creates/updates the build/web folder. Thanks for your reponses though.
